# Chain/maximum elements question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My question: Let S be a two-place division relation on $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. I.e., $a\mid b \leftrightarrow (a,b)\in S$.
Let $C^*=${$C: C \text{ is a chain with respect to} S$}, so $(C^*,\subseteq) $ is a partial order.

- Is there a biggest element in $(C^*,\subseteq)$?
- What are the maximum elements in $(C^*,\subseteq)$?

---

For the first question, I think that it isn't correct, but I am not sure If I'm right.
For the second question, I think that I can arrange the elements in $C^*$ into ascending sub-series, such that in each series the maximum element is co-prime to other's sub-series maximum elements. E.g.,sub-series of powers of primes. I am not sure if I'm correct here too, so I will be glad to get some help.

Comment: You have two orders, which  one do you refer to in the first part?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila I have missed this sorry. Fixed it up!

Comment: What would an element of $C^*$ look like? Would it be a sequence of integers like $2 \sim 4 \sim 24 \sim 144$ (where $\sim$ stands for "divides") or would it be a sequence of ordered pairs? In the former case, I believe the maximal elements will be of the form $p \sim 2p \sim 3p \sim \cdots$ for prime numbers $p$.

Comment: @DanielApsley $C^*$ is a set of ascending dividing series, as written in the question.

Comment: @DanielApsley can you answer my second and first question?